# Implementing Search in a Pre-Populated database with Ionic 2

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I'm currently developing an app with an Acronym Search function tool. I've successfully got the pre-populated database displaying as it should using the SQLite-Ext plugin yet have got stuck as how to implement the search function needed. On the Ionic 2 Site, there's an explanation of how to use the built in 'ion-searchbar' https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar but I can't see how this could be connected to a pre-populated database on the app.

**home.html-**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="queryAcronyms($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let name of acronyms; let nIndex = index">
        <h2>{{ name.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ name.meaning }}</p>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public storage: SQLite;
  private options = { name: "data7.db", location: 'default', createFromLocation: 1 };
  private queryAcronyms = "SELECT * FROM acronymsFinal";
  public acronyms: any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.storage = new SQLite();
    this.storage.openDatabase(this.options).then((success) => {
      this.storage.executeSql(this.queryAcronyms, {}).then((data) => {
        let rows = data.rows;
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            this.acronyms.push({
                name: rows.item(i).name,
                meaning: rows.item(i).meaning
            });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Ideally, I need a search bar right a the top of the page (as I have already put in) which allows you to filter through the data by their the acronyms name. I have also tried running through various other search tutorials but these all either seem to be aimed at Ionic 1 or a database that you populate in the code.

I'm fairly new to Ionic and database control so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a new function with queryAcronyms name like below and filter your data according search query and reinitialize your array

public queryAcronyms(){
    let temparray  =  [];
    temparray =  this.acronyms.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.queryText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
    this.acronyms = temparray;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's something that wasn't explained but I can't get your code working. It keeps on coming up with 'Declaration or Statement expected' and fails to build. Also, is it meant to be 'queryText' in there considering I've never defined that?

Comment: Sorry for not mention about queryText, you can define it in your HomePage class, like

public acronyms: any = [];
queryText = '';

And then bind this queryText with search bar in your view templete file
<ion-searchbar color="primary" [(ngModel)]="queryText" (ionInput)="queryAcronyms()" placeholder="Search"></ion-searchbar> 

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. We're up to the point now that it will build without errors yet search isn't doing anything still. I suspect it's simply to do with placement of code.

Comment: One thing I can't understand is how I'm supposed to use this alongside the previous bit of code. I can't reuse 'public queryAcronyms' like that as it says it's already been used?